# alarmManager.setInexactRepeating does not working exactly on time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to repeat some sort of code on a particular time only i.e at xx:02,xx:17,xx:32,xx:47
i tried using AlarmManager class that brodcast a pending intent.

My problem is that- the following code runs fine on HTC desire 816 and Samsung Galaxy Grand neo but not Gionee M2.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.alarmexample;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        int newmin=0;
        SimpleDateFormat f= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
        long current= System.currentTimeMillis();
        String d= f.format(current);
        String time[]=d.split(":");
        int min = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);
        
        if(min>=0 && min<=2)
        {
            newmin=2-min;
        }
        else if(min<=17)
        {
            newmin=17-min;
        }
        else if( min<=32)
        {
            newmin=32-min;
        }
        else if(min<=47)
        {
            newmin=47-min;
        }
        else 
        {
            newmin=62-min;
        }
        long newtime= current+(newmin * 60 * 1000);
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newtime, 15*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + newmin + " miniuts",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.example.alarmexample;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is up!!!!.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }

}
```

Output on HTC desire 816 and Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo is-

> Time    |  result
>
> xx:02   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration
>
> xx:17   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration
>
> xx:32   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration
>
> xx:47   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration

But on Gionee M2 -

> Time    |  result
>
> xx:00   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration
>
> xx:02   |  nothing happens
>
> xx:17   |  nothing happens
>
> xx:20   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration
>
> xx:32   |  nothing happens
>
> xx:40   |  toast showing message "Time is up!!!!." with 2 Second vibration
>
> xx:47   |  nothing happens

Why the behavior is different when have a same peace of code..
Is am doing something wrong? or anything else..
please tell me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use setExact(int, long, PendingIntent) if you want to have the alarm fired exactly at specified interval.

The cause of your trouble is that you are using a API call to the AlarmManager that is defined as **inexact**. If you look at the documentation for [`setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) you will find this passage.

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but
>   it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time. In
>   addition, while the overall period of the repeating alarm will be as
>   requested, the time between any two successive firings of the alarm
>   may vary. If your application demands very low jitter, use one-shot
>   alarms with an appropriate window instead; see setWindow(int, long,
>   long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).

Comment: But why this happen... running fine in HTC and Samsung not on Ginoee

Comment: Probably a more aggressive power-save-mode. But it is all within specifications

Comment: don't know about phone power-save-mode much...
but have to run code on specific time only